# Rspec failed test: No of inputs of a form count is less than actual inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Suppose a form referenced as:

```
@assign_box = find('.swappy', match: :first)
```

Now, if we count the number of inputs inside the above form, it has an input for authenticity token but not counted here as test case got only seven:

```
expect(@assign_box).to have_css('input', count: 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue.It might be due to environment configs.I need to set allow forgery protection to add authenticity token in test environment.

```
config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = true
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Capybara only finds/counts visible elements, since auth tokens are usually stored in hidden inputs you need to pass visible: :all as an option to have_css

```
expect(@assign_box).to have_css('input', visible: :all, count: 8)
```

Additionally if the form is submitted via ajax (remote form), Rails may not actually be adding the auth token until the submit handles.

Comment: I agreed but I already did that before the test case using                                   before :each do
    Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false

Comment: @Jaswinder  Would be good to point things like that out in future questions. 
 Hopefully you also have an `after :each` that resets that since it's a global setting (it doesn't reset automatically)